# How to detect a touch on a moving (animation) UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimage, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add UITapGestureRecognizer on a UIImageView while its moving but the clic is only working when the animation is static.
I've looked everywhere on the internet but couldn't find a solution.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Here's the code I'm working with: I'm creating 10 "bubbles" containing a round image. I animate them so they're moving up and fading. I'd like to be able to click on them and get their tag (int form 1 to 10).

```
@IBAction func startBubble(sender: AnyObject) {

//var bubble = UIView()
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height

// Animation parameters
let duration : NSTimeInterval = 9.0
var delay : NSTimeInterval = 1.0
var minimumDelay : NSTimeInterval = 3.0
let factor : CGFloat = 1.75
let opacity : CGFloat = 0.3
let options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.CurveEaseIn, .AllowUserInteraction]

for bubbleNumber in 1...10 {

    // Bubble size
    let bubbleWidth : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(40) + 130)
    let bubbleHeight = bubbleWidth
    // Bubble start position
    let startPosition : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenWidth - bubbleWidth)))
    // Bubble delay
    if bubbleNumber > 1 {
        minimumDelay = minimumDelay + NSTimeInterval(3.0)
        delay = minimumDelay + (NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(1000)) / 1000)
    }

    let bubble = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(startPosition, screenHeight, bubbleWidth, bubbleHeight))

    // Bubble definition
    bubble.image = UIImage(named: "bubble.png")
    bubble.tag = bubbleNumber
    bubble.userInteractionEnabled = true
    bubble.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "openBubble:"))

    self.view.addSubview(bubble)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {

        bubble.frame = CGRectMake(startPosition, 1, factor*bubbleWidth, factor*bubbleHeight)

        bubble.alpha = opacity

        }, completion: { animationFinished in

            bubble.alpha = 0.1
            bubble.removeFromSuperview()
    })

}

}  

func openBubble(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
let tappedBubble = sender.view!
print(tappedBubble.tag)
}
```